# How can I reformat blocks of data until the end of the file is reached?

Tags: bash, text-processing, text-formatting

I have a file that looks like this:

```
# Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep Number-of-rows
# Row c_gyrationchunkall
1000 3
1 2.09024e-14
2 4.88628
3 5.69321
2000 3
1 2.10518e-14
2 8.33702
3 8.83162
3000 3
1 1.96656e-14
2 12.1396
3 11.5835
...
```

In my file, the first three lines are always headers. After the headers, my file lists blocks of data of the same size, each starting with a labeling subheader. I want to reorganize the data in my file such that the data in each block are sent into a line starting with the relevant portion of the label of that block and listing the relevant data values of that block afterwards, all separated from each other by spaces. As an example, I want to convert the sample above into:

```
# Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep c_gyrationchunkall
1000 2.09024e-14 4.88628 5.69321
2000 2.10518e-14 8.33702 8.83162
3000 1.96656e-14 12.1396 11.5835
...
```

How do I do this in Bash? I have some experience in Bash, but I'm afraid not enough to handle this problem swiftly...

Comment: `bash` is a poor tool for multiline text processing. Perl (`man perl`) would be a better choice.

Comment: for  the line `1000 3`, what is the significance of the `3`? does this designate the number of follow-on lines? will all such lines *always* have a `3` in the 2nd field or could it vary, and if it can vary, then please update the sample to show an example

Comment: @markp-fuso Yes, 3 designates the number of follow-on lines, and it’s always there. All subheaders have that 3 there.

Comment: Hello, it looks like the header lines change somewhat in the output? Will the output always be first header line as is (no change), and second header line as a combination of rows 2 and 3? Thx!

Comment: @jubilatious1 Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using any awk whether that `3` number of lines in a block can vary or not:

```
$ awk '
    NR == 2 { $3=""; saved=$0; next }
    NR == 3 { $0=saved $3 }
    NR  < 4 { print; next }
    !numLines {
        numLines = $2
        printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
        next
    }
    { printf "%s%s", $2, (--numLines ? OFS : ORS) }
' file
# Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep c_gyrationchunkall
1000 2.09024e-14 4.88628 5.69321
2000 2.10518e-14 8.33702 8.83162
3000 1.96656e-14 12.1396 11.5835
```

---

Following up on a discussion under [Xavier G.s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762956/133219) about a preference in style for readability, here is an awk script written in the same style as that shell script (and contained in a shell script so it behaves the same way externally) but it will run orders of magnitude faster* than and be more robust and portable than the shell script:

```
$ cat ./script_filename
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN {
        # Reformat comments:
        getline first_line
        print first_line
        getline; split($0,line2)
        getline; split($0,line3)
        printf "# %s %s\n", line2[2], line3[3]

        # Reformat data:
        while ( getline > 0 ) {
            timestep=$1; number_of_rows=$2
            printf "%s", timestep
            for ( i=1; i<=number_of_rows; i++ ) {
                getline; row_value=$NF
                printf " %s", row_value
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./script_filename < input
# Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep c_gyrationchunkall
1000 2.09024e-14 4.88628 5.69321
2000 2.10518e-14 8.33702 8.83162
3000 1.96656e-14 12.1396 11.5835
```

* Here's the third-run timing results from running the bash script vs the above awk script on a file containing 90,000 of the OPs records:

```
$ time ./script_bash < file > /dev/null

real    0m9.425s
user    0m5.062s
sys     0m4.139s
```

```
$ time ./script_awk < file > /dev/null

real    0m0.265s
user    0m0.171s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: Puzzled why not #!/usr/bin/env awk -f insead of the shell script with big constant.

Comment: @Joshua you should never use a shebang to call awk, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002754/1745001 for just some of the issues you have to deal with if you do. You obviously don't need to use the same indenting as I used, you could just have `awk 'BEGIN {` and the final `}'` at the start of a line and start every line in between indented once or start them at the start of a line too if you prefer, it won't make much difference to the readability.

Comment: @Joshua Besides what's mentioned in the answer linked by Ed, `#!/usr/bin/env awk -f` wouldn't work on Linux, because everything after the first space is a single argument. `env` wouldn't be able to find the executable `awk -f`.

Comment: @JoL: Now I understand why `muawk` exists. (`muawk` filename just did `exec awk -f filename $@` although it wasn't written in shell.) I still have a copy of it on a superformatted floppy disk if I can find a way to read it again. Having not ever actually needed to worry about `env awk -f` I never found out it wouldn't work. Hmm. I wonder if I'm hallucinating a memory or if it is actually smart enough to split its argument if invoked directly by #!.

Comment: @Joshua I don't know `muawk`. Trying to make sense of it from your description, I guess it was actually `exec awk -f "$@"`, so the shebang would be `#!/usr/bin/env muawk`. `muawk` wouldn't have any need to split arguments. You know, `#!/bin/awk -f` does also work. It just means you hardcode the location instead of using `$PATH` via `env`.

Comment: @JoL: All the uses of it I saw in the wild were either `#!/bin/muawk` or `#!/bin/muawk options`. Note that `-f` didn't ever need to be given. Had the author known about `--` (which he most definitely didn't) I'm pretty sure it would have added `--` after the first argument.

Comment: It was a very strange system. Most of the textutils were actually written in awk, and sendmail was written in this weird combination of awk and sh.

Answer (score 3):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*Use `skip` to forget about header lines for the moment:*

```
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.skip(3).rotor(4, partial => True).map: *.words; .[0,3,5,7].put for @a;'  file

#OR

~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines.skip(3).batch(4).map: *.words; .[0,3,5,7].put for @a;'  file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, `lines` are read in, `skip`ping the first 3 header lines. Every 4 lines are `rotor`ed/`batch`ed together, including final `partial` "rotorings" at the end of the file. While we're at it, let's break each `rotor`/`batch` into whitespace-separated `words`.

These rotor/batches-of-4-lines-each-broken-on-whitespace are saved in an `@`-sigiled Array called `@a`. Finally (in the second statement), using `for` each `@a` position is iterated through and out`put`, taking care that unwanted elements are dropped (via indexing brackets `[0,3,5,7]`).

Sample Input:

```
# Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep Number-of-rows
# Row c_gyrationchunkall
1000 3
1 2.09024e-14
2 4.88628
3 5.69321
2000 3
1 2.10518e-14
2 8.33702
3 8.83162
3000 3
1 1.96656e-14
2 12.1396
3 11.5835
```

Sample Output:

```
1000 2.09024e-14 4.88628 5.69321
2000 2.10518e-14 8.33702 8.83162
3000 1.96656e-14 12.1396 11.5835
```

---

Regarding the header lines, it could be just as easy to start the Raku code with two `put` statements, e.g. `put "Time-averaged data...";` etc. But indeed, following works to give the output desired by the OP:

```
~$ raku -e 'lines[0].put; .words[0..1, *-1].put for lines[0..1].rotor(2);  \
            my @a = lines.rotor(4, partial => True).map: *.words;          \
            .[0,3,5,7].put for @a;'  file
## Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep c_gyrationchunkall
1000 2.09024e-14 4.88628 5.69321
2000 2.10518e-14 8.33702 8.83162
3000 1.96656e-14 12.1396 11.5835
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 3):

Using *AWK*:

```
$ awk '
    NR==2{sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"");rec = $0; next}
    NR==3{$0 = rec OFS $NF};
    NR<4;                                
    NR>3{printf "%s", (NR%4==0) ? ((NR==4) ? "" : ORS) $1 : ($1="")$0 }
   END{if (NR)print ""}'
```

```
$ awk '
   NR==2{sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,"");rec = $0; next}
   NR==3{$0 = rec OFS $NF};
   NR<4;
   $NF ~ /^[0-9]+$/{a=$NF;n=NR+a; sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,""); printf "%s", $0; next}                    
   NR<=n{$1 =""; printf "%s", $0((NR==n) ? ORS : "") }'
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty anwser -- feel free to run `shellcheck` on this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Reformat comments:
read -r first_line
echo "${first_line}"
read -r sharp line2_word1 line2_word2
read -r sharp line3_word1 line3_word2
echo "# ${line2_word1} ${line3_word2}"

# Reformat data:
while read -r timestep number_of_rows; do
    echo -n "${timestep}"
    for (( i=1; i<=number_of_rows; i++ )); do
        read -r row value
        echo -n " ${value}"
    done
    echo
done
```

Usage: `./script_filename < input`

Limitations:

- this script assumes data lines are ordered (i.e. 1, 2, 3, as shown in the example)
- this script does not handle interrupted data (e.g. announcing 3 lines of data but providing only 1)

Comment: Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: My first thought was to answer with a well-presented Perl one-liner but I decided to stick with bash because the question is "How do I do this in Bash?" and I still think "Don't" is too dogmatic, especially since I perceive that readability is more important than performance here (I could be wrong though, only OP can tell).
In the meantime, I ran shellcheck on my side and adjusted a couple things. Do you see security issues in the code above?

Comment: When people ask "how do I do this in bash?" they're never asking for how to do it using only bash builtins. I don't see any security issues but those `echo`s will do different things depending on which version of `echo` you're picking up and what the values of the variables are. You could use `printf '# %s %s\n' "$line2_word1" "$line3_word2"`, for example, to remove that issue. Other than that it'd just be orders of magnitude slower to run than an awk (or sed, perl, etc.) script.

Comment: If it's that you find the style you used to be more readable than idiomatic awk, you can write exactly the same style of code in awk using `getline` instead of `read`. I added an awk script to the end of [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/762969/133219) that shows how to do that.

Comment: Ah, yes, the builtin echo could be disabled and we could pick a variant that does not support -n. (also, xpg_echo could be on) printf could also be disabled, but the behaviour of %s and \n remains reliable. Essentially, the fact that bash builtins can be disabled is indeed a strong argument.

Comment: Your second version of your awk answer is indeed much more appealing.

Comment: I understand why you'd feel that way. It took me a bit of usage to really appreciate and understand the benefits of awk already having the while-read loop, splitting input into fields, and condition{action} body structure built into the tool/language.

Comment: I just added some timing results to the bottom of my answer too in case you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveats mentioned in your question and using your sample input as file q762948, you can do this by a simple awk command:

```
$ head -2 q762948 >result.txt
# dump the comments as required
$ tail +4 q762948 | awk '{c=(NR-1)%4} c==0{p=$1;print ""} c>0{p=$2}{printf p"  "}'>>result.txt    
$ cat result.txt

# Time-averaged data for fix avetimeall
# TimeStep Number-of-rows

1000  2.09024e-14  4.88628  5.69321  
2000  2.10518e-14  8.33702  8.83162  
3000  1.96656e-14  12.1396  11.5835
```